# GIT, How to confirm commit zillions of files for deletion?

Tags: git

after issuing

```
git commit
```

I see vi open with something like that

```
# Changes to be committed:
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon1024.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD20.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD20@2x.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD29.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD29@2x.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD40.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD40@2x.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD76.png
#       deleted:    MyApp (original)/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon_IPAD76@2x.png
```

and I am supposed to remove the # at the beginning of each line.

The problem is that this list contains 2000 lines (yes I want to delete everything).

Is there a more sane way to confirm every entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to delete the `#` at the beginning of each. The contents of that file are an example commit message. Anything with a `#` in front of it is a comment. git will take anything that's not a comment and make that the commit message.

I would recommend using the `-m` flag after git commit.  For example `git commit -m 'deleted a bunch of files'`

This makes it so that you don't have to edit a file every time, just type your commit message into the command line.